# How component can get another component as an input?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components

I can set **string** or **number** as the input of component:

```
@Input('name') name: string;
```

and use it in HTML file:

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

but I want to set a **component** instead of the string, like `name`

In other words: How can I set a **component** for the input of another **component**?

Comment: what is your requirement? From the question it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: if you want to load a component inside another component, you can try using `ng-content`

Comment: you can't use component for input, but you can put component in a template, and template can be passed into input

Comment: You actually can bind a component via `Input` but not for the purpose of rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Embedding Element Or Component Inside Another Component You Can Use `ng-content` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'outer-CMP',
  template: `
    <div> </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styleUrls: [....]
})
export class OuterInputComponent {

}
```

then :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-CMP',
  template: `
    <div> </div>

  `,
  styleUrls: [....]
})
export class InnerInputComponent {

}
```

Use :

```
<outer-CMP> 
        <inner-CMP>
        </inner-CMP>
</outer-CMP>
```

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't use an `input` for this, you will need to use content projection with [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild#example).

Example taken from Angular Docs:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <tab>
      <pane id="1" *ngIf="shouldShow"></pane>
      <pane id="2" *ngIf="!shouldShow"></pane>
    </tab>

    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
  `,
})
export class ContentChildComp {
  shouldShow = true;

  toggle() { this.shouldShow = !this.shouldShow; }
}
```

The `pane` component, is projected in the `tabs` component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <div>pane: {{pane?.id}}</div>
  `
})
export class Tab {
  @ContentChild(Pane, {static: false}) pane !: Pane;
}
```

You get access to the `pane` component within the `tab` component by using `@ContentChild`.

A full guide on [content projection](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/)